# Subsetting first Observation per id and date in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to subset the first date per observation per id. For example, just get the rows for the first date in which observations A and B appeared. If we have the following dataset:

```
df =
id date Observation
1  3    A
1  2    B
1  8    B
2  5    B
2  3    A
2  9    A
```

the outcome should look like this:

```
df =
id date Observation
1  3    A
1  2    B
2  5    B
2  3    A
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the order being different, it can be accomplished using `dplyr` by grouping then slicing:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table("id date Observation
1  3    A
1  2    B
1  8    B
2  5    B
2  3    A
2  9    A")

df %>%
    group_by(id, Observation) %>%
    slice(1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   id, Observation [4]
#>      id  date Observation
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1     1     3 A          
#> 2     1     2 B          
#> 3     2     3 A          
#> 4     2     5 B
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, Observation) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()

# OR

df %>% 
  group_by(id, Observation) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```